# Installing external wireless card on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wifi, usb, dkms

I am trying to use my TP-Link AC1300 external wireless usb with my ubuntu 16.04 distro (on Acer E15 laptop).

I'm running into major difficulties as it does not detect my usb stick.

```
yannik@yannik-aspire:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b573 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3015 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2357:010d  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2357:010d` should show a name next to it corresponding to my USB stick.

Also I can't figure out which driver I need to install for this.

Comment: https://github.com/Grief/archer-t4u\

Comment: Thanks! But how do I resolve this error now?

`Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=4.13.0-26-generic -C /lib/modules/4.13.0-26-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/archer-t4u/4.8.1/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for archer-t4u: 4.8.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.13.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/archer-t4u/4.8.1/build/make.log for more information`

Comment: Read the last line of that text and do it; the driver might not be appropriate for your kernel version.

Comment: See this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345920/153195